# A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source dsMyData. Winforms

Tags: .net, winforms, report

I'm trying to figure out how to supply the data source in my c# code behind. I'm attempting to use one combobox with all my reports listed and one report viewer as the primary container for these reports. Here is my code:

```
        private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'bgdataDataSet.FoodTable' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.FoodTableTableAdapter.Fill(this.bgdataDataSet.FoodTable);
        BindingList<Data> _comboItems = new BindingList<Data>();
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Select", RptValue = "Select" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "All Food Values", RptValue = "AllFoodValues.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "All Readings", RptValue = "AllReadings.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Avg Food Values by Date", RptValue = "AvgFoodValuesByDate.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Avg Food Values by Meal", RptValue = "AvgFoodValuesByMeal.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Avg Readings by Date", RptValue = "AvgReadingsByDate.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Avg Readings by Time", RptValue = "AvgReadingsByTime.rdlc" }); 
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Avg Readings by Event", RptValue = "AvgReadingsByEvent.rdlc" }); 
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Blood Pressure Chart", RptValue = "BPChart.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Blood Pressure Report", RptValue = "BPReport.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Detailed Food Values by Meal", RptValue = "DetailFoodValuesByMeal.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Doctor Detailed Report", RptValue = "DoctorDetailedReport.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Food Chart", RptValue = "FoodChart.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Pumper Detail Report", RptValue = "PumperDetailReport.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Reading Charts", RptValue = "ReadingCharts.rdlc" });
        _comboItems.Add(new Data { Name = "Total Daily Food Intake", RptValue = "TotalIntakeDailyFood.rdlc" });
        comboBox1.DataSource = _comboItems;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "RptValue";
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = "Select";
        this.rvDoctorReportViewer.RefreshReport();
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0)
        {
            string strReport;
            strReport = "ReportViewer." + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
            rvDoctorReportViewer.Reset();
            rvDoctorReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports/" + comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString() + "";
            rvDoctorReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = strReport;
            rvDoctorReportViewer.RefreshReport();

        }
```

I am thinking somewhere in the block of code private void comboBox1 that I can specify this but I'm not certain how. Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would post my solution to this problem. I added a table to the database for report configuration. This way I can add or remove reports in the future. It contains columns such as report name, report friendly name, report path, and dataset so this way I can simply use the values from the field to avoid this problem.